# Damaging headphones jack in phones

Tags: headphones

Could they have been damaged by plugging the headphones midway by mistake once or is that harmless unless you do it all the time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's harmless even if you do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

this should not damage your headphone. you may do it always(I myself am using this method to listen to music for more than a year)

Answer (score 0):

If you plug in the headphone jack halfway you may get only one channel, that is mono sound when it should be stereo, but doing this will not cause any damage to the headphones. Plugging in the headphone jack firmly will make it have a proper electrical connection and prevent it from wiggling in its socket.